# Specifying Custom dimensions for a Shield UI Background image

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I have a site where I am providing users some graphical information and I use the Shield UI JavaScript Chart. I am trying to take some more advanced use of the chartAreaBackgroundImage:  property. I am actually in need of several things I couldn’t find anything in the manuals.

1. Is there a way to resize the picture by a certain factor e.g. to specify exact dimensions?
2. Is it possible to set transparency for the image used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images used as the chart background, set by the chartAreaBackgroundImage property have currently no more adjustable properties than the URL of the image itself. 
Once rendered, the image fills the entire plot (or data) area of the chart.

In addition there is no transparency factor that can be adjusted as well, however you may adjust the images forehand and also use appropriate dimensions of the chart and data area, so that the desired visual effect is achieved.